# How to create a Page alias in WordPress

Tags: plugins, posts, pages, options

[image]

In the image you see... WordPress has alias for Pages like **Home Page**, **Checkout Page**, **Privacy Policy Page** and any appear beside the page you assign them.

How to create this feature in WordPress? If I want to alias a page like **XYZ Page** and when I assign any page to that alias... **XYZ Page** appears beside the assigned page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are actually post states; not aliases.. And you can do it through the [`display_post_states`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/display_post_states/) filter, like so, where we check if the post ID (`$post->ID`) is `123` and if so, we assign the `XYZ Page` state to that post (which could be a Page, Custom Post Type, etc.):

```
add_filter( 'display_post_states', 'my_post_states', 10, 2 );
function my_post_states( $post_states, $post ) {
    if ( 123 === $post->ID ) {
        $post_states['xyz_page'] = 'XYZ Page';
    }

    return $post_states;
}
```

And for reference, this is the conditional which WordPress uses for the "Front Page" and "Posts Page" states:

```
if ( 'page' === get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) {
    if ( intval( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) === $post->ID ) {
        $post_states['page_on_front'] = __( 'Front Page' );
    }

    if ( intval( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) === $post->ID ) {
        $post_states['page_for_posts'] = __( 'Posts Page' );
    }
}
```