# How to code custom special page

Tags: theme-development, pages, code

I'm looking for how to code custom "special" page as use many plugins. An idea is that I have in theme links to the custom special page. Then admin can chose which of his pages is the one "special" page.

The functionality I'm looking for is similar as functionality of for example "Shop page" in woocommerce.

[image]

[image]

I appreciate any help or a documentation link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Page alias in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/318050/how-to-create-a-page-alias-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you asked "How to Code", here is my guide to get you started.

1. Create a menu page in the administration area using [add_menu_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/)
2. Create the form using html **select** form-element
3. Populate the form-element with all **pages**. To get all pages you can use [get_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/)
4. Save the form using [admin_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) action
5. Save the selected-item of the form using [update_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/)
6. To get the saved option you can use [get_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/)
7. To add that **— Special Text** in the page list, you need to filter the title. If the page's ID is equal to the saved_setting, then append that text. I'm not sure which hook to use, I think it is [manage_pages_columns](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_pages_columns)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution could work! Do you also know how to mark such page among others as on my second attached image?

Comment: You need to create a filter for the title in **Pages-list**. And if the column ID is equal the setting, you append that **— Special Text**) in the title. I haven't tried this, but I think this is the hook https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_pages_columns

Comment: Ok, I'll do so. Thank you for your help.