# How to filter page title for certain page?

Tags: filters, pages, admin, title

I have saved in DB in options an ID of certain page. I wanna use that ID to filter corresponding page title and add a postfix in pages overview as follow.

[image]

So for example to add postfix "- My Chosen Page" on my ID's page. I got a tip on [manage_pages_columns](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_pages_columns) filter but either I can't use it properly or it isn't a filter I need.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/318050/how-to-create-a-page-alias-in-wordpress/318052?r=SearchResults#318052).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Page alias in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/318050/how-to-create-a-page-alias-in-wordpress)

Comment: @SallyCJ - Thank you men. You made my day. Works perfectly!